# Rails Server won't start after Ruby upgrade - Segmentation Fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After upgrading my Ruby to 1.9.3-p429, I tried to start the Rails server. It told me rails was not installed so, I boldly did a 'gem install rails'. Now when I try to start the server, I'm getting this:

```
andrunix@amp-laptop~/code/madrilla$ rails s
/Users/andrunix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

Abort trap: 6
```

I have no idea why that says, "ruby 1.8.7" in that output. Perhaps that's a clue to my problem.

But anyway, super frustrated at this point.

And by the way, this is on OS X.

Help me please!

Comment: I updated mysql with 'brew install mysql' and still had the problem. I restarted the computer and it is now working. Scared the hell out of me though. I don't need problems like that right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the version you've installed as the default for your whole system:

```
rvm --default use  ruby-1.9.3-p429
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Alcides. I usually use a .ruby-version file in my working directories as I have different projects that use different versions of Ruby. I suppose that would still work but your suggestion probably just sets the default.